# Can a Chrome Extention listen to system audio and not just a tab or input mic? How can I access all the existing audio with just a chrome extention?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-extension, audio-recording, call-recording

Is there a way for a chrome extension to listen to more than just a tab or one mic?

I need to listen to the audio of a softphone that runs on a separate desktop app separate of chrome.

I would want to get that audio into the chrome extension. So my audio and the audio of the person I am talking to would both be accessible by the extension.

Is there anything that would make it possible without the need to setup some additional virtual inputs? I just want to be able to use an Extention give it some permissions and then listen to all the audio.

Comment: Extensions can't do it, but you can write a separate utility and run it from the extension via [nativeMessaging](https://3-72-0-dot-chrome-apps-doc.appspot.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).